Sketch always appears to show data one iteration of main loop behind
I'm trying to emulate a display similar to an old fashioned mechanical bathroom scale, ie the pointer stays in the middle of a small screen and the scale moves left or right as needed.
I am using an Arduino Nanpo with IDE 1.6.13 My problem is that the display is always one iteration of the loop behind on the screen. For example if the previous value was 49.98 and the new value is 50.00, I would expect the screen to "move" to the right by two increments e.g the screen would show
49.97 | 49.98 | 49.99 then move by one to show 49.98 | 49.99 | 50.00 then move my one again to show 49.99 | 50.00 | 50.01
The code I use is working i.e. the "shifting" is occurring, however the problem is the display always shows the previous value even though I can prove that the current value is being passed to the shift routines. BUT when the next current value is being processed the display THEN shifts to the previous current value which on this iteration is now the previous. In other words the display is always one iteration behind the current value. This is my first post. I also have a video which if the forum rules allow, I can upload which perfectly illustrates the problem. In the meantime here's a snapshot image...
Here's my code:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>

#define cs   10
#define dc   8
#define rst  9

Adafruit_ST7735 display = Adafruit_ST7735(cs,  dc, rst);

int box_y_coord = 25;               // Start of y coordinate for boxes
int box_width = 70;
int box_height = 30;
int box_speed = 2;
int box_offset = 80 - (box_width / 2); // value is currently 45
int shi;
int sli;

bool initialisation_required = true;

int random_frequency;
int current_frequency;
int previous_frequency = 5000;
int shift_in_frequency;

void setup() {

  display.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  display.setRotation(1);           // x begins at left-hand side of the screen, y begins from the top of the screen
  display.setTextColor(ST7735_BLACK);
  display.setTextWrap(0);
  display.setTextSize(2);

  Serial.begin (9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));


  display.fillRect(0,0,160,25,ST7735_YELLOW);  // remove when problem fixed
  display.fillRect(0,55,160,25,ST7735_YELLOW); // remove when problem fixed

  delay(5000); // Give me time to start video

}

void loop() {

  current_frequency = random(4997,5004);
  shift_in_frequency = current_frequency - previous_frequency;
  display.fillRect(0,60,160,80,ST7735_WHITE);
  display.setCursor(2,65);
  display.print("Current:");
  display.print(current_frequency);
  display.setCursor(2,85);
  display.print("Previous:");
  display.print(previous_frequency);
  display.setCursor(2,105);
  display.print("Shift:");
  display.print(shift_in_frequency);
  Serial.print("In main loop - current: ");
  Serial.print(current_frequency);
  Serial.print(" previous: ");
  Serial.print(previous_frequency);
  Serial.print(" shift: ");
  Serial.println(shift_in_frequency);
    
  if (abs(shift_in_frequency) > 5)
     initialisation_required = true;

  if (initialisation_required) {
     setup_initial_display();
     initialisation_required = false;
  }

  if (shift_in_frequency > 0) { // Frequency rising
      shift_higher(shift_in_frequency);
  }
  else if (shift_in_frequency < 0) { // Frequency falling
          shift_lower(0 - (shift_in_frequency));
          }

  previous_frequency = current_frequency;
  shift_in_frequency = 0;
  delay(3000);
  
}

void setup_initial_display() { //Runs once only

  // Draw the left-hand box
  display.drawRect(box_offset - box_width,box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
  display.fillRect(box_offset - box_width + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
  // Draw in the frequency
  display.setCursor(box_offset - box_width + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
  display.print(int(current_frequency - 0.01) / 100);
  display.print(".");
  if (int(current_frequency - 0.01)%100 < 10)
     display.print("0");
  display.print(int(current_frequency - 0.01) % 100);

  // Draw the central box
  display.drawRect(box_offset,box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
  display.fillRect(box_offset + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
  // Draw in the frequency
  display.setCursor(box_offset + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
  display.print(int(current_frequency) / 100);
  display.print(".");
  if (int(current_frequency)%100 < 10)
     display.print("0");
  display.print(int(current_frequency) % 100);

  // Draw the right-hand box
  display.drawRect(box_offset + box_width,box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
  display.fillRect(box_offset + box_width + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
  // Draw in the frequency
  display.setCursor(box_offset + box_width + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
  display.print(int(current_frequency + 0.01) / 100);
  display.print(".");
  if (int(current_frequency + 0.01)%100 < 10)
     display.print("0");
  display.print(int(current_frequency + 0.01) % 100);

  // Draw the gauge line
  display.drawFastVLine(79,25,30,ST7735_RED);
  display.drawFastVLine(80,25,30,ST7735_RED);
  display.drawFastVLine(81,25,30,ST7735_RED);
  display.drawFastVLine(82,25,30,ST7735_RED);

}

void shift_higher(int offset) {
  Serial.print("In shift higher - current: ");
  Serial.print(current_frequency);
  Serial.print(" previous: ");
  Serial.print(previous_frequency);
  Serial.print(" shift: ");
  Serial.println(shift_in_frequency);
  
  shi =  box_width + box_offset; // Is 70 + 45 = 115
  while(shi <= ((offset * box_width) + box_width + box_offset)) { // For example when offset = 1,  limit = 1 * 70 + 70 + 45 = 185

      // Starting box
      display.drawRect(shi - box_width,box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
      display.fillRect(shi - box_width + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(shi - (box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
      display.print(int(current_frequency) / 100);
      display.print(".");
      if (int(current_frequency)%100 < 10)
         display.print("0");
      display.print(int(current_frequency) % 100);

      // Previous minus one - SR1
      display.drawRect(shi - (2 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
      display.fillRect(shi - (2 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(shi - (2 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
      display.print(int(current_frequency - 1) / 100);
      display.print(".");
      if (int(current_frequency - 1)%100 < 10)
         display.print("0");
      display.print(int(current_frequency - 1)%100);

      // Previous minus two - SR2
      display.drawRect(shi - (3 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
      display.fillRect(shi - (3 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(shi - (3 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
      display.print(int(current_frequency - 2) / 100);
      display.print(".");
      if (int(current_frequency - 2)%100 < 10)
         display.print("0");
      display.print(int(current_frequency - 2) % 100);

      // Previous minus three - SR3
      if (offset > 1) {
        display.drawRect(shi - (4 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(shi - (4 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(shi - (4 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 3) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency - 3)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 3) % 100);
      }

      // Previous minus four - SR4
      if (offset > 2) {
        display.drawRect(shi - (5 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(shi - (5 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(shi - (5 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 4) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency - 4)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 4) % 100);
      }

      // Previous minus five - SR5
      if (offset > 3) {
        display.drawRect(shi - (6 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(shi - (6 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(shi - (6 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 5) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency - 5)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 5) % 100);
      }
      // Previous minus six - SR6
      if (offset > 4) {
        display.drawRect(shi - (7 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(shi - (7 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(shi - (7 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 6) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency - 6)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency - 6) % 100);
      }

      // Draw the gauge line
      display.drawFastVLine(79,25,30,ST7735_RED);
      display.drawFastVLine(80,25,30,ST7735_RED);
      display.drawFastVLine(81,25,30,ST7735_RED);
      display.drawFastVLine(82,25,30,ST7735_RED);

      shi = shi + offset;
  }
}

void shift_lower(int offset) {   // sli decreases

  Serial.print("In shift lower - current: ");
  Serial.print(current_frequency);
  Serial.print(" previous: ");
  Serial.print(previous_frequency);
  Serial.print(" shift: ");
  Serial.println(shift_in_frequency);

  sli = 0;
  while(sli >= 0 - ((offset * box_width) + 25)) {

      // Starting box
      display.drawRect(sli + box_width,box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
      display.fillRect(sli + box_width + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(sli + (box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
      display.print(int(current_frequency) / 100);
      display.print(".");
      if (int(current_frequency)%100 < 10)
         display.print("0");
      display.print(int(current_frequency) % 100);

      // Next plus one - SL1
      display.drawRect(sli + (2 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
      display.fillRect(sli + (2 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(sli + (2 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
      display.print(int(current_frequency + 1) / 100);
      display.print(".");
      if (int(current_frequency + 1)%100 < 10)
         display.print("0");
      display.print(int(current_frequency + 1)%100);

      // Next plus two - SL1
      display.drawRect(sli + (3 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
      display.fillRect(sli + (3 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
      display.setCursor(sli + (3 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
      display.print(int(current_frequency + 2) / 100);
      display.print(".");
      if (int(current_frequency + 2)%100 < 10)
         display.print("0");
      display.print(int(current_frequency + 2) % 100);

      // Next plus three - SL2
      if (offset > 1) {
        display.drawRect(sli + (4 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(sli + (4 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(sli + (4 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 3) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency + 3)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 3) % 100);
      }
      // Next plus four - SL3
      if (offset > 2) {
        display.drawRect(sli + (5 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(sli + (5 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(sli + (5 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 4) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency + 4)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 4) % 100);
      }
      // Next plus five - SL4
      if (offset > 3) {
        display.drawRect(sli + (6 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(sli + (6 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(sli + (6 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 5) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency + 5)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 5) % 100);
      }
      // Next plus six - SL5
      if (offset > 4) {
        display.drawRect(sli + (7 * box_width),box_y_coord,box_width,box_height,ST7735_BLACK);
        display.fillRect(sli + (7 * box_width) + 1,box_y_coord + 1,box_width - 2,box_height - 2,ST7735_WHITE);
        display.setCursor(sli + (7 * box_width) + 6,box_y_coord + (box_height / 2) - 6);
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 6) / 100);
        display.print(".");
        if (int(current_frequency + 6)%100 < 10)
           display.print("0");
        display.print(int(current_frequency + 6) % 100);
      }

      display.drawFastVLine(79,25,30,ST7735_RED);
      display.drawFastVLine(80,25,30,ST7735_RED);
      display.drawFastVLine(81,25,30,ST7735_RED);
      display.drawFastVLine(82,25,30,ST7735_RED);

      sli = sli - offset; // was box_speed
  }
  
}


Here's some serial monitor output (nb not the same time as the screen image previously sent
In main loop - current: 4997 previous: 5000 shift: -3
In shift lower - current: 4997 previous: 5000 shift: -3
In main loop - current: 4999 previous: 4997 shift: 2
In shift higher - current: 4999 previous: 4997 shift: 2
In main loop - current: 4999 previous: 4999 shift: 0
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 4999 shift: 2
In shift higher - current: 5001 previous: 4999 shift: 2
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 5001 shift: 0
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 5001 shift: 0
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 5001 shift: 0
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 5001 shift: 0
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 5001 shift: 0
In main loop - current: 5000 previous: 5001 shift: -1
In shift lower - current: 5000 previous: 5001 shift: -1
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 5000 shift: 1
In shift higher - current: 5001 previous: 5000 shift: 1
In main loop - current: 4997 previous: 5001 shift: -4
In shift lower - current: 4997 previous: 5001 shift: -4
In main loop - current: 5001 previous: 4997 shift: 4
In shift higher - current: 5001 previous: 4997 shift: 4
In main loop - current: 5003 previous: 5001 shift: 2
In shift higher - current: 5003 previous: 5001 shift: 2

IN all of the above, the screen displays the previous frequency and not the current

I think the problem may lie in the shift procedures as the screen correctly displays the current frequency upon invoking the setup_initial_display procedure. It's almost as if the ST7735 display is not flushing the display in a timely manner?

Put another Serial.print() debug statement within the while() loop of both shift_higher() and shift_lower(). These may be executing more often than you would like. If that doesn't bring anything, reduce shift_higher() and shift_lower() to simply printing the starting box and no while loop.

I've solved the problem. It's because I was using the wrong value in the shift routines, ie I was using current_frequency instead of previous_frequency. After all I want to know what the frequency has changed FROM not TO :slight_smile: On changing that and swapping the calls to higher and lower around, it all works perfectly. Problem solved. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

I'm not sure how to mark this question as solved - any suggestions please?

write an answer and accept it as a solution

I've solved the problem. It's because I was using the wrong value in the shift routines, ie I was using current_frequency instead of previous_frequency. After all, I want to know what the frequency has changed FROM not TO :slight_smile: On changing that and swapping the calls to shift_higher and shift_lower around, it all works perfectly. Problem solved. Thanks to all for your suggestions
